# Nested form with multiple of the same key names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I am trying to get the following params into a Rails form.

```
{:routine=>{
 :name=>"Test"}, 
  :arbitrary=>[
   {:lift=>{
    :exercise_id=>"1", 
    :infos=>[
     {:weight=>"250", :repetiton=>"8"}, 
     {:weight=>"275", :repetition=>"6"}
            ]
           }
   },
   {:lift=>{
    :exercise_id=>"2", 
    :infos=>[
     {:weight=>"405", :repetition=>"12"}, 
     {:weight=>"445", :repetition=>"4"}
            ]
           }
   }
              ]
}
```

In learned how to properly set a form in rails I have realized that deciding what I would like my params to be before I begin constructing the form is very helpful.  I am running into a problem at an early stage in my form.

In the above params, we have an routine which has a name.  That routine has many lifts, which is a joins between the routine and the exercise.  In a select field, I am attempting to have a user pick an exercise from the Exercise.all and set the instance of exercise as the exercise_id so that along with a routine_id, a lift can be created.  Each lift is going to have many sets (infos in the params shown above, rails would not let me use set), which have weight an repetitions.

In the short form that I currently have, the last exercise that I choose is the only exercise being passed in the params.  I am guessing because when mass assigning, the first :lift gets overridden by the second :lift and so on.  Here is the form I currently have

```
<%= form_tag routines_path %>

<%= label_tag "routine[name]", "Routine Name" %>
<%= text_field_tag "routine[name]" %><br />

<%= select("arbitrary[][lift]", "exercise_id", Exercise.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id] }) %><br />

<%= select("arbitrary[][lift]", "exercise_id", Exercise.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id] }) %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit Routine" %>
```

Is there a way I can accomplish these params or am I going for the wrong params in general.  I am guessing that if each :lift was called something different that would work but not what I am trying to do.  Thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: What about "arbitrary[][lift][1][]"and "arbitrary [][lift][2][]" ?

Comment: When I give the form "arbitrary[][lift[1]" and then [2] for the next field it works.  The issue is when I down the road would like a user to dynamically add how many different exercises they choose to which would make this type of hard coding more challenging but its a good starting point.

Comment: Would there be a way to dynamically change the number here [][lift][1][]?

Comment: So are you adding a partial each time the user says "another arbitrary, please?"  Through Ajax? You could then build it using a session variable.

Comment: You could have something like...<% 0...counter do |current_count|%>

Comment: ... and then use #{current_count} in the select string your building and then <% end %> to end the loop... so counter will control how many arbitrary will show and each will have a different number

Comment: this is rambling, sorry... let me format it into an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many "arbitrary" you want to create, you can create them with a loop...

```
<% 0...@maximum.each do |current_count|%>
  <%= select("arbitrary[][lift][#{current_count}][]", "exercise_id", Exercise.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id] }) %><br />
<% end %>
```

Each will have a unique number so they'll create separate param sets that can be iterated through.

You just need to set  @maximum before you render the form.

Comment: Works, then simply using the |k,v| in the loop will do the trick